Sequelize DatabaseError "missing FROM-clause entry for table" filtering nested include / join
I have double nested include / join of tables.
I need to filter first include using second includes column
In the end I want to filter users that have no linked items in associated table.
I'm using Sequelize in Nest.js with PostgreSQL
users.findAll({
  raw: true,
  nest: true,
  where: {} //something
  include: [
    {
      model: OneTimeUrlModel,
      required: false,
      where: {
        '$sent_msgs.id$': { [Op.ne]: null },
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: SentMsgModel,
          attributes: ['id'],
          required: false,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});

I get this SQL:
SELECT "UserModel"."id", "UserModel"."phone", "urls"."id" AS "urls.id", "urls"."user_id" AS "urls.user_id", "urls->sent_msgs"."id" AS "urls.sent_msgs.id" 
FROM "users" AS "UserModel" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "urls" AS "urls" ON "UserModel"."id" = "urls"."user_id" AND "sent_msgs"."id" IS NOT NULL 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "sent_msgs" AS "urls->sent_msgs" ON "urls"."id" = "urls->sent_msgs"."url_id";

and an Error:
error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "sent_msgs"

How do I make this work?
It's not clear from this example, but what I really want is to filter only "bad" urls and pick users without them (users that have urls = null).
So I can't move "where" above to users.
I also can't move "where" below to the sent_msgs as filtering depends on type of url as well.

Ok, so it turned out in cases like this you need to explicitly set "as".
And if you check the field of joined table it should be required.
users.findAll({
  raw: true,
  nest: true,
  where: {} //something
  include: [
    {
      model: OneTimeUrlModel,
      required: false,
      where: {
        '$otu_urls.otu_sent_msgs.id$': { [Op.ne]: null }, //CHANGED THIS
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: SentMsgModel,
          attributes: ['id'],
          as: 'sent_msgs', //ADDED THIS
          required: true, //CHANGED
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});

(I also changed column name format)
Now I have to figure out how to get wanted results
